# Render partial without having to duplicate things over and over

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my interface

```
    interface IBase
{
    string MvrId { get; set; }
    string IndividualFullName { get; set; }
    string FirstHospitalCaseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class

```
public class AddMedicineModel:IBase
{
    private MedicalVarianceEntities DbCtx = new MedicalVarianceEntities();
    public AddMedicineModel(int MvrId)
    {

        Mvr Mvr = DbCtx.Mvrs.Find(MvrId);
        this.MvrId = Mvr.PKMvrId.ToString();//for display purposes
        IndividualFullName = Mvr.IndividualLastName 
                             + ", " 
                             + Mvr.IndividualFirstName;
        FirstHospitalCaseNumber = Mvr.CaseNumber.ToString();

    }


    //IBASE INTERFACE IMPLEMENTATION 
    public string MvrId { get; set; }
    public string IndividualFullName { get; set; }
    public string FirstHospitalCaseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my partial view! NOTICE THAT MY Partial view is not attached to my AddMedicineModel

Therefore, I cant re-use it with other models that inherit from IBase.How can I make a re-usable partial view for many models.

```
@model MedicalVariance.Models.ViewModels.AddMedicineModel
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MvrId)
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IndividualFullName) 
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstHospitalCaseNumber)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare it as taking the interface:

```
@model IBase
```

Comment: freaking love it. I dint know you could pass an interface. I was thinking they were not being able to instatiate but I guess it doesnt work that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have the best of both worlds:

*Partial-AddMecicineModel.cshtml*

```
@model MedicalVariance.Models.ViewModels.AddMedicineModel

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PropertyInAddMedicineModelNotInInterface)
@Html.Partial("Partial-IBase", Model)
```

*Partial-IBase.cshtml*

```
@model IBase

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MvrId)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IndividualFullName) 
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstHospitalCaseNumber)
```